# Load a class in a field of the same module - OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, module, field, odoo

I need to load data from a class, into a field of another class in the same module.

I need this to show a tree of data in the xml view.

```
class certificados(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.certificados'
_description="Certificados de No Produccion"
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

_columns = {
            'Item' : fields.integer('Item'), 'Registro_Numero' : fields.integer('Registro Numero'),
            'Fecha_de_Emision': fields.date('Fecha de Emision', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_de_Solicitud': fields.date('Fecha de Solicitud', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_del_Documento': fields.date('Fecha del Documento', required=True, select=True),
            'Vigencia' : fields.integer('Vigencia'), 'cert_ids' : fields.one2many('certificados.line','requisicion_id','Items del Certificado',states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}),
            'descripcion' : fields.text('Descripcion'),
            'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
            }
certificados()

class certificados_line(osv.osv):

_name = "certificados.line"
_description="Certificados No Produccion"

_columns = {
    'Codigo_Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
    'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
    'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Especificaciones_Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
    'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
    'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.float('Valor En Divisas'),
    'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
    'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),

}
certificados_line()
```

I've seen in another module that the first class doesn't close itself, i mean, in this class 'certificados' wouldn't have the 'certificados()' code in the bottom.

Don't know if this is possible, or if i'm doing something wrong here.

The view of 'cert_ids' field of certificados, should be of the form:

```
                   <notebook>
                      <page string="Productos">
                            <field name="cert_ids">
                                <tree string="Productos">
                                    <field name="product_id"/>
                                    <field name="Codigo_Arancelario"/>
                                    <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria"/>
                                    <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad"/>
                                    <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado"/>
                                    <field name="Valor_En_Divisas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad_Consumida"/>
                                    <field name="notas"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                            <separator string="Observaciones"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
```

I don't know if i'm doing something wrong, but the xml gives me invalid architecture errors, and the field is not working correctly.

Thanks in advance!

---

After the correction made by user1576199, it is still giving me the error, does anybody knows if there's an error in the codes?

These are the Pastebins

[xml](http://pastebin.com/S9LxcbWq)

[python](http://pastebin.com/EFdW7P5j)

Answer (score 1):

Hello use this view.

```
                      <notebook>
                          <page string="Productos">
                                <field name="cert_ids">
                                    <tree string="Productos">
                                        <field name="product_id"/>
                                        <field name="Codigo_Arancelario"/>
                                        <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria"/>
                                        <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas"/>
                                        <field name="Cantidad"/>
                                        <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado"/>
                                        <field name="Valor_En_Divisas"/>
                                        <field name="Cantidad_Consumida"/>
                                   </tree>
                                </field>
                                <separator string="Observaciones"/>
                                <field name="descripcion"/>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
```

You used `<field name="notas"/>` which does not exits in **certificados.line** object.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i tried but still getting the error, at invalid xml for view architecture, these are the codes [xml](http://pastebin.com/S9LxcbWq) and [python](http://pastebin.com/EFdW7P5j)

Comment: Nevermind i think i got it, so i opened a new question, thank you!